# Terraform config for updating already existing launch template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deployment, continuous-integration, terraform

I am trying to update my already existing launch template on AWS using Terraform.
Below is the config for Terraform.

```
resource "aws_launch_template" "update" {
  name = data.aws_launch_template.config.name
  image_id = data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id
  instance_type = "c5.large"
//  arn = data.aws_launch_template.config.arn
}
```

On passing the name it is throwing error 400 with the below error.

```
Error: InvalidLaunchTemplateName.AlreadyExistsException: Launch template name already in use.
```

I want the same launch template with just update version. Couldn't able to find any documentation on terraform official website for modifying templates. Or am I missing something?

OS - macOS Catalina

Terraform version - `v0.12.21`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing to note about terraform in general is that it wants to own the entire lifecycle of any resources it manages.

In your example, `aws_launch_template.update` with that name already exists, so terraform says, essentially, "I don't own this resource, so I shouldn't change it."

This is actually a pretty nice benefit because it means that terraform wont (or at least shouldn't) overwrite or delete resources that it doesn't know about.

Now, since you are referencing an existing launch template, I would recommend bringing it under terraform's ownership (that's assuming you're allowed to do so). To do this, I would recommend

- Hard-coding the launch template's name in the resource itself, rather than referencing it via `data`, and
- [Importing the resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/launch_template.html#import) by running a command like so

```sh
 terraform import aws_launch_template.update lt-12345678
```

Where you would replace `lt-12345678` with your actual launch template ID. This will bring the resource under terraform's ownership and actually allow updates via terraform code.

Just be careful that you're not stepping on the toes of someone else's resources, if you are in a context where this was created by someone else.

Comment: that works like a charm. But I guess it would a good practice for us if we go by the default behavior of Terraform. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying this now and getting "Resource instance key must be given in square brackets." with `terraform import module.cms-test.aws_launch_template.launch-template.update lt-12345678`. Will post back what ends up working.

Comment: It was because my resource was named "launch-template" instead of "update", copy/paste/reading error, works!